# Is it possible to get the picture token from Picture Class?

Tags: windows-phone-7

to receive a Picture over Picture Hub this code works fine:

```
MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary();
            Picture picture = library.GetPictureFromToken(NavigationContext.QueryString["token"]);
```

Is it possible, to get the token string from the Picture instance?
Any casts your tricks?

Answer (score 1):

To uniquely identify a `Picture` in the `MediaLibrary` you'l need to use a combination of `Name` and `Date`.

You coudl also try using `HashCode` but when you have a large number of images it can be easier to find an image by name than checking the HashCode of all images.

Comment: This is a good workaround!
Too bad that is not possible to get a token from an Picutre instance.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can gather, the token is provided to your application (intended as an "Extras" application) by the operating system, but there is no way for you to get a token for a specific image. What are you trying to achieve? Are you creating a Silverlight or XNA application?

You may find the following resources useful:

- [WP7–Adding to the Image Hub 'extras' menu](http://www.dotnetdoc.com/PermaLink,guid,039a2c5e-121d-4503-8927-1c59f09d7e83.aspx)
- [WP7 Saving to Media Library](http://thesociablegeek.com/2011/01/15/wp7-saving-to-media-library/)

Comment: I need a Unique ID to save additional data for each picture. I create a Silverlight application.